# Bxslider: Gray Area at the bottom of Image Slider

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, bxslider

I'm working on adding bxslider to my Rails web project. I have it added sucessfully. However, what is annoying is that even after altering several CSS feautures, there is gray area at the bottom that does not go away. I've tried setting various heights to 100%, but does not work. I also tried eliminating any borders or padding, which still doesn't do the trick. Has anyone experienced the same issue or knows how to eradicate the gray body part so that images fit the entire height of the slider?

[image: Here's an example of the gray area..]

Comment: To help us provide a solution, you would need to provide code examples. This question may fit better onto a forum dedicated to the bxslider framework.

Comment: If you place the code in a place like fiddle, it would be a lot easier to view/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! I realized that in order to get rid of the grey area, I needed to adjust the height of the iframe itself, and not tamper too much with the CSS related to the images within the slider or any of its contents.